# Name java:comp is not bound in this Context javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat6

This is my code:

```
   Context ctx  = new InitialContext();
   Context envCtx = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

It usually works fine, but sometimes it throws this error:

```
Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

This is my context.xml:

```
<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

   <Environment name="fileLocation" value="dev" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>

   <Environment name="log4JFileLocation" override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="dev"/>
```

Any ideas of what is going on?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to tell us more about the tomcat context. Did you define anything in your context.xml ?

Comment: Yep I did, need anything else?